# How to hide an image from web browser network

Tags: javascript, web, server-side

I had a side project (find Waldo) written in Javascript, and there are some puzzle images we hide under a dark background.

https://github.com/zoetian/wheres_waldo

Is there anyway to hide it so that some of the smart players cannot find it from network?

Thanks

Comment: non-related, pretty cool product you have!

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a directory along with an `.htaccess` file which contains `Deny from all`